# Get the last occurrence of an object based on the value of a field

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

From an array like:

`[{'name': 'a', 'val': 1}, {'name': 'b', 'val': 2}, {'name': 'a', 'val': 3}]`

I want to get to:

`[{ name: 'b', val: 2 }, { name: 'a', val: 3 }]`.

This can be achieved for example by:

`arrOut = _.uniqBy(arrIn.reverse(), 'name').reverse();`

but I am looking for a faster/cleaner method without the need for reversing the whole array twice.

Comment: Should the original order be preserved?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason for reversing the array again at the end.

Comment: You won't find a **cleaner** method than what you've got...it's quite elegant.  If you want **faster** then the method using a `Set` proposed by @FelixKling will give you > 2x performance.  This is almost entirely due to the extra work `_uniqBy` is doing to determine uniqueness and not the extra reverse (reversing an array is actually quite fast).  I threw together a jsperf to demonstrate that [can be viewed here](https://jsperf.com/get-the-last-occurrence-based-on-a-field/1)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea: Iterate over the array twice. First time count the number of occurences of each name, the second time filter out elements if their respective count isn't 1.

Example:

```js
const arrIn = [{'name': 'a', 'val': 1}, {'name': 'b', 'val': 2}, {'name': 'a', 'val': 3}];

const counter = Object.create(null);
for (const element of arrIn) {
  counter[element.name] = (counter[element.name] || 0) + 1;
}

const arrOut = arrIn.filter(element => counter[element.name]-- === 1);
console.log(arrOut);
```

Another way would be to iterate over the array in reverse order, keeping track of the names you have seen and call `.reverse` on the result:

```js
const arrIn = [{'name': 'a', 'val': 1}, {'name': 'b', 'val': 2}, {'name': 'a', 'val': 3}];
const arrOut = [];

const seen = new Set();
for (let i = arrIn.length; i--;) {
  if (!seen.has(arrIn[i].name)) {
    arrOut.push(arrIn[i]);
    seen.add(arrIn[i].name);
  }
}

console.log(arrOut.reverse());
```

Comment: Two interesting approaches, I have added the missing input data (`arrIn`) on the first example. Also, you can avoid the `reverse()` on the second example, if you use `unshift()` in replacement of `push()`.

Comment: I thought about this, but I figured it's worse to reindex the result array in every iteration vs just reordering them once at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

This method removes the first array element

Answer (score 0):

If the original order should be preserved, one alternative approach is to use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in conjunction with [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). This is my attempt to preserve the original order of the elements:

```js
let input = [
  {'name': 'a', 'val': 1},
  {'name': 'b', 'val': 2},
  {'name': 'a', 'val': 3}
];

let res = input.filter(
    ({name, val}, idx, arr) => !arr.some((o, j) => o.name === name && j > idx)
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Alternatively, a more efficient approach can be done using [Array.reduceRight()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) and a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to keep track of already visited names (as **@Felix Kling** show in one of his examples)

```js
let input = [
  {'name': 'a', 'val': 1},
  {'name': 'b', 'val': 2},
  {'name': 'a', 'val': 3},
  {'name': 'b', 'val': 12},
  {'name': 'c', 'val': 7},
  {'name': 'b', 'val': 22}
];

let res = input.reduceRight((acc, obj) =>
{
   if (acc.visited.has(obj.name))
       return acc;

   acc.visited.add(obj.name);
   acc.res.unshift(obj);
   return acc;

}, {res: [], visited: new Set()});

console.log(res.res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```